# How to pass a char to `boost::char_separator<char>`

Tags: boost

Based on [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

```
explicit char_separator(const Char* dropped_delims,
                        const Char* kept_delims = "",
                        empty_token_policy empty_tokens = drop_empty_tokens)

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main(int, char**)
{
    string text = "token, test   string";

    char_separator<char> sep(", ");
    tokenizer< char_separator<char> > tokens(text, sep);
    BOOST_FOREACH (const string& t, tokens) {
        cout << t << "." << endl;
    }
}
```

I need to pass in a char as the separator as follows:

```
void splitString(const string& text, char sepChar)
{

    char_separator<char> sep(&sepChar);
    tokenizer< char_separator<char> > tokens(text, sep);
    BOOST_FOREACH (const string& t, tokens) {
        cout << t << "." << endl;
    }
}
```

Question> Is this right way to convert `char` to `const char*` for `boost::char_separator`?

Thank you

Comment: Do you receive a compilation or run time error?